# Mono for Android: Spinner ItemSelected event triggers on load but shouldn't?

Tags: android, events, triggers, xamarin.android, spinner

I have a spinner with a few values and I fill it from my webservice.

**Filling the spinner**

```
int i = 0;

var dropItems = new List<SpinItem2>();

DataRow[] result = myOPTvalues.Tables[0].Select("FieldValue=" + item.FieldValue);
foreach (DataRow row in result)
{
    var optItem = new PrevzemSpin();
    optItem.FieldValue = row["FieldValue"].ToString();
    if (optItem.FieldValue.Equals(""))
    optItem.FieldValue = null;

    optItem.FieldTextValue = row["FieldTextValue"].ToString();
    if (optItem.FieldTextValue.Equals(""))
    optItem.FieldTextValue = null;

    dropItems.Add(new SpinItem2(i, optItem.FieldValue.ToString(), optItem.FieldTextValue.ToString()));
            }

i = 1;
foreach (DataRow row in myOPTvalues.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var optItem = new PrevzemSpin();
    optItem.FieldValue = row["FieldValue"].ToString();
    if (optItem.FieldValue.Equals(""))
    optItem.FieldValue = null;

    optItem.FieldTextValue = row["FieldTextValue"].ToString();
    if (optItem.FieldTextValue.Equals(""))
    optItem.FieldTextValue = null;


    if (optItem.FieldValue != item.FieldValue)
    {
        dropItems.Add(new SpinItem2(i, optItem.FieldValue.ToString(), optItem.FieldTextValue.ToString()));
    }
    ++i;
}
```

For some reason it acts like the item that was inserted first is "selected" on default and then triggers the ItemSelected event which I use to send the selected but I don't want that.

Since there's quite a number of these spinners on my screen it really slows down the activity plus it also sends the incorrect values to the field and since I use the ItemSelect to detect if everything went OK (let's say the service fell or the values themselves changed on server (someone added a new field on the server application) while the user is completing the form etc.)

Is there someway to tell the app not to trigger that on activity load but on actual user interaction?

Comment: In Android, by default, spinner 1st item gets selected and executes code inside onItemSelected(...) while loading. So, Paolo's answer should do the work. Myself implemented this in 1 of my projects and its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I declared GetView:

```
int LastSpinnerSelectedPosition;
```

Inside my spinner definition:

```
LastSpinnerSelectedPosition = 0;
```

My spinner ItemSelected event:

```
var CurrentSelectedIndex = SpinnerValue.SelectedItemPosition;

if (CurrentSelectedIndex != LastSpinnerSelectedPosition) 
{
    // WHATEVER I WANTED TO DO ON ITEM SELECT ANYWAY

    // Fix the LastSpinnerSelectedPosition ;)
    LastSpinnerSelectedPosition = CurrentSelectedIndex; 
}
```

Simple ;D

Comment: Yep that'd do it.  For a bonus badge you can accept you own answer!

Comment: I know :) But I have to wait a day :)

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for Android specifically, but I have encountered this many times with Windows.

The solution I usually use is to simply add a boolean `loading` variable.  Set it to true at the beginning of your initialisation and then clear it at the end.

In your event handlers like `ItemSelected` you can simply check if this is being triggered as the result of the initial load.

```
private void onItemSelected(....)
{
    if(loading)
    {
        return; //Ignore as form is still loading
    }

    //Normal event handling logic goes here
    ....
 }
```

Comment: Just set `loading = false` at the end of your initialisation method.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/54N0HFEx where in this code would that be?
Hint - // if field is ComboBOX is where my spinner code resides.

Comment: I'd put `loading = true` at the beginning of `GetView` and `loading = false` right at the end of that method.  I also highly recommend you split that method up into smaller subroutines, it's way too long to be readable or maintainable at the moment.

Comment: Did you add the bit above in my answer to check for the flag when the event handler is called?

Comment: Hi! I already resolved it with a different approach (but quite similar to yours - will post the solution first thing when I get to my code tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarification, the event fires when an item is selected. The semantics are obviously flawed, but technically the item IS selected when it initially loads since you can then immediately ask the spinner for which item is selected, so as the other answers say, just ignore the first time it is selected since it's guaranteed to be the loading select, and then proceed as normal after that.

Comment: Yeah I've read upon the subject. I understand the underlying logic behind how the spinner works but it lacks a let us say a  "OnUserItemSelect"/"OnUserItemTouch" method so we could avoid making workarounds each time a spinner gets in play :)